# How to merge method invocation with same parameter in java elegantly

Tags: java

**Background:**

1. I got a java method `queryDB` with a parameter `p`, and `queryDB` is resource consuming.
2. For each parameter `p`,  the result of `queryDB` may vary over time.

**What I want to achieve:**

If someone calls `queryDB` with parameter `p=x` and there is another thread already called `queryDB` with same parameter `p=x` and waiting for results, this thread will not actually execute `queryDB`, insteads waiting for results from another thread.

> Note: I know how to implement this in vanilla java, but I want a one-liner solution.

**vanilla java:**

```
public class InvocationMerger<K, R> {
    private Map<K, CompletableFuture<R>> futureMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public R invoke(K key, Function<K, R> func) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        AtomicReference<CompletableFuture<R>> createdFutureRef = new AtomicReference<>();
        CompletableFuture<R> pendingFuture = futureMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> {
           createdFutureRef.set(new CompletableFuture<>());
           return createdFutureRef.get();
        });

        if (createdFutureRef.get() != null) {
            CompletableFuture<R> createdFuture = createdFutureRef.get();
            try {
                R result = func.apply(key);
                futureMap.remove(key, createdFuture);
                createdFuture.complete(result);
                return result;
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                futureMap.remove(key, createdFuture);
                createdFuture.completeExceptionally(e);
                throw e;
            }
        } else {
            return pendingFuture.get();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how will you implement this in vanilla java ?

Comment: Use a [Guava Cache](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) (or a similar ready-made solution). Implementing this manually and correctly is much trickier than it looks at first glance. Certainly not a one-liner.

Comment: Maybe this? https://www.yegor256.com/2014/08/03/cacheable-java-annotation.html

Comment: @Jabir I am thinking of a solution like these, but unfortunately this doesn't support invalidate cache on method return.